# template function override

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I am trying to create a template speacialization for a function which is based on a type

So for eg for the type number I have

```cpp
template <class ElementType, typename = typename TEnableIf<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, double>>::Value>::Type>
void WriteExtras(IGLTFJsonWriter &Writer, const FString &Key, const TSharedPtr<FJsonValue> &Value) const
{
    Writer.Write(Key, float(Value->AsNumber()));
    // Perform further processing or write logic for double
}
```

Now I want to have one more definition but for bool ...but if I try do

```cpp
template <class ElementType, typename = typename TEnableIf<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, bool>>::Value>::Type>
void WriteExtras(IGLTFJsonWriter &Writer, const FString &Key, const TSharedPtr<FJsonValue> &Value) const
{
    Writer.Write(Key, Value->AsBool());
    // Perform further processing or write logic for double
}
```

I get an error `Function already defined`

I call the function template as

```cpp
WriteExtras< EJson>(Writer,Key, Pair.Value);
```

The EJson is an enum

```cpp
enum class EJson
{
    None,
    Null,
    String,
    Number,
    Boolean,
    Array,
    Object
};
```

After @Jan suggestion following is my template implementation

template <bool Condition, typename T = void>
using EnableIf_t = typename TEnableIf<Condition, T>::type;

```
template <class ElementType>
auto WriteCustom(IGLTFJsonWriter& Writer, const FString& Key, const TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>& Value) const
    ->EnableIf_t<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, FString>>::Value>
    //->TEnableIf<TIsSame<ElementType, FString>::Value>
{
    Writer.Write(Key, Value->AsString());
    const FText Title = FText::FromString(TEXT("Template"));
    FMessageDialog::Open(EAppMsgType::Ok, FText::FromString(TEXT("FString")), &Title);
}


template <class ElementType>
auto WriteCustom(IGLTFJsonWriter& Writer, const FString& Key, const TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>& Value) const
    ->EnableIf_t<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, bool>>::Value>
    //->TEnableIf<TIsSame<ElementType, FString>::Value>
{
    Writer.Write(Key, Value->AsBool());
    const FText Title = FText::FromString(TEXT("Template"));
    FMessageDialog::Open(EAppMsgType::Ok, FText::FromString(TEXT("Bool")), &Title);
}
```

and when I try to call

```
WriteCustom<EJson>(Writer,Key, Pair.Value);
```

it gives error

Comment: It looks like the first one is enabled for everything *except* `double`, the second for everything *except* `bool` - and every type is either "not `double`" or "not `bool`". `EJson` is neither, so both templates are instantiated.

Comment: One possible alternative is that your free function have a single template argument and then call a function with an extra argument (with a distinct type for each possibility) or a template class specialization.

Comment: I would expect to see the use as either `WriteExtras<float>(Writer,Key, Pair.Value);` or `WriteExtras<EJson::Number>(Writer,Key, Pair.Value);` (with a non-type parameter). That the type is `EJson` provides no useful information.

Comment: @molbdnilo that is what I want to avoid , specifying the type ...I want the template to deduce the type from my FJsonValue

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar I had a hunch about that. It can't do that; templates are instantiated and selected at compile-time and can't depend on runtime values.

Answer (score 2):

These two functions actually declare the same function:

```cpp
template <class ElementType,
          class = typename TEnableIf<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, double>>::Value>::Type>
void WriteExtras(/* same as below */) const;

template <class ElementType,
          class = typename TEnableIf<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, bool>>::Value>::Type>
void WriteExtras(/* same as above */) const;
```

The only difference between them is the default argument to a template parameter, but that is not making one of these a separate entity. It's like writing:

```cpp
int foo(int x = 0); 
int foo(int x = 1);
```

### Doing SFINAE with `enable_if` correctly

You need to do SFINAE with `std::enable_if` (or your custom imitation) somewhere else in the function signature, such as parameters, noexcept specifications, return types, etc. For functions, one of the best approaches is to use the return type, because it doesn't change the template parameter list:

```cpp
// convenience alias (since C++14)
// similar to std::enable_if_t
template <bool Condition, typename T = void>
using EnableIf_t = typename EnableIf<Condition, T>::type;

// note: you could also make a convenience variable template for TIsSame

template <class ElementType>
auto WriteExtras(/* ... */) const
  -> TEnableIf_t<not TIsSame<ElementType, double>::Value>;
// note: TNot is unnecessary, you can just write '!' or 'not' here

template <class ElementType>
auto WriteExtras(/* ... */) const
  -> TEnableIf_t<not TIsSame<ElementType, bool>::Value>;
```

Alternatively, some people prefer to do the SFINAE part in another non-type template parameter (NTTP):

```cpp
template <class ElementType, TEnableIf_t<not TIsSame<ElementType, double>::Value, int> = 0>
void WriteExtras(/* ... */) const;
```

The reason why this works is because the functions would have a different type for that NTTP, so the functions aren't actually the same. It also wouldn't be possible to bypass the constraint by providing a template argument explicitly.

### Alternative solutions

However, it's also highly questionable whether you should be using SFINAE here at all. You can achieve the same with `if constexpr` (C++17):

```cpp
template <class ElementType>
void WriteExtras(/* ... */) const {
    if constexpr (TIsSame<ElementType, double>::value) {
        // ...
    }
    else if constexpr (TIsSame<ElementType, bool>::value) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // TODO: handle this error case somehow
        //       (specifics may depend on language version and compiler)
    }
}
```

You can also use full specializations, as long as there is only one template parameter:

```cpp
template <class ElementType> // Inside class
// Primary template is defined as deleted, so only calling
// the specializations is allowed.
void WriteExtras(/* ... */) const = delete;

template <> // Outside class
void JsonWriter::WriteExtras<double>(/* ... */) const { /* ... */ }

// More specializations here ...
```

Comment: can t I add or condition in 
template <class ElementType, typename = typename TEnableIf<TNot<TIsSame<ElementType, double> || bool >::Value>::Type>
    void WriteExtras(IGLTFJsonWriter& Writer, const FString& Key, const TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>& Value) const ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar you can to an extent, but not with default arguments to type parameters. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: it needs c++ 20 ? I get an error on Vs 2022
a non-type template-parameter of type 'TEnableIf<TNot<TIsSame<T,double>>::Value,int>' requires at least '/std:c++20'

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar Look again, it's just `TEnableIf_t`, which makes the template parameter effectively an `int`, since it uses the convenience alias.

Comment: ok I was able to build ...what should be my call to WriteExtras ?
Writer => IGLTFJsonWriter , Key =>String Pair.Value) => TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>
WriteExtras<EJson>(Writer, Key, Pair.Value); ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar I don't know what you're trying to express with that arrow syntax. How you constrain your function shouldn't really affect call syntax; what you were doing before should still work, regardless where the `EnableIf` is positioned.

Comment: I am getting this error 
 ambiguous call to overloaded function 
when I try to call
WriteExtrasEJson>(Writer, Key, Pair.Value);

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on compiler explorer or something?

Comment: I was able to build by using different return types . I want to know how do I call these template functions . I could call using 
WriteCustom<bool>(Writer, Key, Pair.Value);
WriteCustom<FString>(Writer, Key, Pair.Value);
but I want to call something like 
WriteCustom<EJson>(Writer, Key, Pair.Value);

Comment: Yeah, the syntax you've used is how you should be calling these functions. What's the issue with the `WriteCustom<EJson>(...)` call?

Comment: I have shared the code snippet in the edits

Comment: For the deleted proposal I get the error 
const': attempting to reference a deleted function 
for the call 
WriteX<EJson>(Writer, Key, Pair.Value);

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar can you try to make it reproducible though? I don't have the definition of all the types available, and you didn't post the exact error message either, so I can't really help you.